# How does setInputVerifier(InputVerifier inputVerifier) work?

Tags: java, swing, input, user-input

I've got code:

```
public class SerialNumberInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {
@Override
public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
    String text = ((JTextField) input).getText();
    if(text.length()!=6)
        return false;
    try {
        Integer value = Integer.parseInt(text);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine, do all the checkings. But I'm not sure about setInputVerifier(InputVerifier inputVerifier). It just doesn't allow me to input to another field, but I simply can push a button and a wrong data have been sended. So how could I possibly handle that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) from [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html).

Basically, what it is allowing you to do is determine if focus should be taken away from the field or not depending on whether you think the input is valid or not

Try overriding [`shouldYieldFocus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html#shouldYieldFocus%28javax.swing.JComponent%29) to stop the field from losing focus when it's invalid